# Fragment pager adapter and transaction replacment

Tags: android

I have 6 fragments and a main activity. when I do a `Transaction .replace` I only can do it with fragments 4-6. if I replace the first 3 fragments (e.g. `.replace(R.id.Frag3,fragmet)`) my game crashes when i do the transaction.And when i replace Fragment 6 with Fragment 3 in:

```
 @Override
 public Fragment getItem ( int arg0){
     switch (arg0) {
         case 0:
             return new Frag1();
         case 1:
             return new Frag2();
         case 2:
             return new Frag6();
         case 3:
             return new Frag4();
         case 4:
             return new Frag5();
         case 5:
             return new Frag3();
         default:
             break;
            }
     return null;
 }
```

Fragment 3 woks and Fragment 6 crashes so its the first `case`s that crash the game in .replace. PLZ HELP! Thank You.

the fragments are almost identical.

Main activity:

```
package com.redot.puzzle3;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
  import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.TextView;

  import org.w3c.dom.Text;


  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Frag5.F5toF4 , 
   Frag5.F5toF6{


    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

   private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Remove title bar
    //  this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new 
   SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

       FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) 
       findViewById(R.id.fab);
      fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                      .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}

public void setF4Riddle(int x){
    Frag4 F4 = 
  (Frag4)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag4);


    if (F4 != null ) {
        F4.getF4Riddle(x);

    } else {
        Frag4 fragment = new Frag4();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("Value", x);
        TextView Dialog =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Dialog);
        Dialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frag4_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        fragment.getF4Riddle(x);
    }


}

 public void setF6Riddle(int x) {

     Frag6 F6 = (Frag6)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag6);

        if (F6 != null) {
            F6.getF6Riddle(x);
        } else {
            Frag6 frag = new Frag6();
           Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("Value", x);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            TextView dialog =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialog);
            TextView Q =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.questions);
            Button Q1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question1);
            Button  Q2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question2);
            dialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Q.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Q1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Q2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frag6_container, frag)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            frag.getF6Riddle(x);
    }
}


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 6;
        }


        @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                return new Frag1();
            case 1:
                return new Frag2();
            case 2:
                return new Frag3();
            case 3:
                return new Frag4();
            case 4:
                return new Frag5();
            case 5:
                return new Frag6();

            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Inventory";
            case 1:
                return "3Men";
            case 2:
                return "Test";
            case 3:
                return "TheMan";
            case 4:
                return "King";
            case 5:
                return "Farmer";

        }
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Main_activity layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.redot.puzzle3.MainActivity">

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is the probably the stacktrace for the crash:

```
10-09 00:01:46.985 20690-20690/com.redot.puzzle3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.redot.puzzle3, PID: 20690
                                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0098 (com.redot.puzzle3:id/frag3) for fragment Frag3{128ae004 #5 id=0x7f0d0098}
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1326)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:725)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Fragment 6:

```
  package com.redot.puzzle3;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.CountDownTimer;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;

 public  class Frag6 extends Fragment {

Button startTime;
Button Q1;
Button Q2;
TextView Q;
TextView dialog;
int counter=3;
int questions =0;
int Riddle=1;
boolean Run=true;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag6, container, false);


    dialog =(TextView)myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.dialog);
    Q =(TextView)myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.questions);

    dialog.setText("Do You Have ?");
    startTime = (Button) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.startTimer);
    Q1 = (Button) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.question1);
    Q2 = (Button) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.question2);

    Q.setText("Questions: "+ questions +"/5");

    askQuestion();
    SetRun();
    runTimer();

    return myInflatedView;
}










 private void askQuestion(){
    Q1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("FFF", "riddle: "+Riddle);
            questions++;
            Q.setText("Questions: "+ questions +"/5");
            dialog.setText("Answer1");
            startTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Q1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Q2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

    });
    Q2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            questions++;
            Q.setText("Questions: "+ questions +"/5");
            dialog.setText("Answer2");
            startTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Q1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Q2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

    });
}
private void runTimer() {

    startTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (questions == 5) {
                dialog.setText("Sorry I cant help any further");
                startTime.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Q1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Q2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Run=false;
                return;
            }
            startTime.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long milisec) {
                    counter--;
                    dialog.setText("Timer: " + counter);
                    if(Riddle==2){
                    }
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    if (questions < 5) {
                        counter = 3;
                        dialog.setText("Do You Have Q?");
                        dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Q1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Q2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                }
            }.start();
        }

    });
}

private void SetRun(){
    if(Riddle==2){
        questions=0;
        Run=true;
    }
}




public void getF6Riddle(int x){
    Riddle=x;
}
```

}

Fragment 6 layout:

```
     <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/frag6_container"
      tools:context="com.redot.puzzle3.Frag6">

  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="784dp"
    android:layout_height="1127dp"
    android:id="@+id/frag6"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/question1"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="177dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.176"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/question2"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="177dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.843"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startTimer"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="177dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog"
        android:layout_width="593dp"
        android:layout_height="318dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.549"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.194"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questions"
        android:layout_width="252dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.163"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment 3:

```
    package com.redot.puzzle3;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;


 public  class Frag3 extends Fragment {

int Riddle;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag3, 
   container, false);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return myInflatedView;
}



}
```

Fragment 3 layout:

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/frag3"
tools:context="com.redot.puzzle3.Frag3">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->



 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `No view found for id 0x7f0d0098`

Comment: You have used such type of view id which is not exist in xml of fragment 6.

Comment: show respective  java class and xml

Comment: ok but why when i swap the fragment 6 and 3 fragment 3 works

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya what is respective java class

Comment: @amirsoltani fragment6 and its layout

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya sure 1 second

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i've done it Fragment 3 is empty btw.

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal thats not the stacktrace for fragment 6 its for fragment 3 and im pretty sure i used the right id also when i change the frag 6 and frag 3. frag 6 stops working and 3 works (opposite of now)

Comment: @amirsoltani sorry show `Frag3`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya right on

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya done

Comment: @amirsoltani Just clean-Rebuild-Restart your IDE

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya ok let me try

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya is it file>invalidate/restart

Comment: @amirsoltani yes.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it still crashes. :(

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I think there is something wrong about the first 3 `case`s pretty sure. all of them crash the app only those three

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya when I analyzed the stacktrace it underlined this:  `at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063)` how can i read it?